# Fast modular calculation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Pow(x,2)=13 (mod N)

For figuring out the x value in huge numbers N, any fastest method? N is a square number and the range 1<N<pow(10,30)

Comment: What means "N begins from 1 to pow(10,30)"? Do you want to solve "Pow(x,2)=13 (mod n)" for a huge n? Can you give an example for n? Why do you need to solve this equation?

Comment: If n is prime, you can use [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm). If n is not prime, solving for x is equivalent to factorising according to that page.

Comment: I need to solve a binary quadraric form problem and to search x values in a loop, but for sure I need a fast calculation algorithm. N is a square number in a loop . The loop starts from 1 and ends pow (10,30)

Comment: Do you mean : What are the solutions (if there are some) for $$x^2\equiv 13\mod n$$ for $1\le n\le 10^{30}$ ?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Fortunately, in the range the author needs, factorization is absolutely routine.

Comment: Yes and n is a square number, exactly. Thanks

Comment: Pleas could you rewrite your post so that it is understandable? Is N and n the same number?

Comment: So the module n is a square number?

Comment: So you could factorise $N$ (you only need factorise its square root, a 15 digit number), use a generalisation of Tonelli-Shanks to solve the equation modulo each prime power that is in the factorisation of $N$, and then use the Chinese remainder theorem to combine those to get the solutions to the original modulo $N$ equation. A computer could do all this in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks :) checking that algorithm.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%3D13+modulo+123456789012342%5E2) can solve this easily.